# How does this 'sed' substitution command with lots of @ signs work?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

Can anyone explain how this `sed` command works?

```
sed 's@+@ @g;s@%@\\x@g' | xargs -0 printf "%b"
```

Comment: The normal way to do this is using slashes, but that may become cumbersome if you search and replace something with slashes.  That is not the case here, so even though it is perfectly fine it confuses future maintainers like you.

Comment: … and leads them to learn something new about `sed` this way! :)

Answer (score 15):

In sed, substitute commands are usually written as `s/pattern/replacement/options`. However, it's not necessary to use `/` - you can use other characters if it is convenient, so it could be `s@pattern@replacement@options` or `s:foo:bar:g`. `s@+@ @g` is like `s/+/ /g` - replace all `+` with spaces. Similarly `s@%@\\x@g` replaces all `%` with `\x` (a single backslash is an escape character in sed, so you need two to get an actual backslash).

A string like `foo+%2Fbar` will then become `foo \x2Fbar`. `printf "%b"` will expand the backslash-escaped sequences like `\x2F` (the ASCII character whose hexadecimal value is 2F, which is `/`) to finally give you `foo /bar`.

Comment: In brief, a URL->filename decoder.

Answer (score 10):

[The command you're asking about for decoding `+`es and `%` sequences from URLs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187256/11938) is not just a `sed` command, it's a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) that processes input with [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sed.1.html), then pipes it to [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xargs.1.html) for further processing. First lets look at the `sed` command:

```bash
sed 's@+@ @g;s@%@\\x@g'
```

You may be more accustomed to seeing it with `/` rather than `@` as the separator, which could easily have been done here without complication since `/` appears in neither of the search patterns nor either of the replacement texts. This command is equivalent:

```bash
sed 's/+/ /g;s/%/\\x/g'
```

Like `/`, `@` is a perfectly good punctuation character for `sed`.

On each line of input:

1. `s@+@ @g` (`s/+/ /g`) substitutes (`s`) occurrences of `+` with a space. This affects all `+`es on a line (`g`), not just the first one.
2. `;` ends the action ("command") and allows you to specify another one in the same "script."
3. `s@%@\\x@g` (`s/%/\\x/g`) substitutes (`s`) occurrences of `%` with `\x`. As before, it acts on all rather than just the first of each line (`g`).

   In `\\x` the `\\` represents just one `\` because `\` has a special meaning to `sed`. Its special meaning is actually as the character you use to take away the special meaning of another character that comes after it that would otherwise have special meaning. So it must be escaped as `\\`.

---

Now let's look a the `xargs` command, whose purpose is to run [`printf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/printf.1.html).

`xargs` constructs command lines. If you run `xargs command...`, where *`command...`* is one or more word, `xargs` runs *`command...`* with additional [command-line arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments) read from its input. In this case, the input to `xargs` is the output of `sed`, because of the pipe (`|`). Normally `xargs` interprets any whitespace in its input to mean that the text before and after it constitutes separate arguments, but the `-0` option makes it split arguments at occurrences of the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) instead.

*In the intended use of your command, a null character won't appear* and `xargs` will run `printf %b` with just one additional command-line argument, the output of the `sed` command. Thus, while not equivalent in general, in this case the whole pipeline might instead have been written like this using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) instead of `xargs`:

```bash
printf '%b\n' "$(sed 's/+/ /g;s/%/\\x/g')"
```

As for what `printf` is intended to do here, [**as muru says**](https://askubuntu.com/a/961881/22949) the `%b` format specifier consumes and prints an argument (like `%s`) but causes backslash escapes--of the sort the `sed` command on the left side of the pipe was written to generate--to be [translated into the characters they represent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_(Unix)).

Suppose I run that command and pass `http://foldoc.org/debugging%20by%20printf` as input. I get `http://foldoc.org/debugging by printf` as output, because the `%20` sequences are translated into spaces.

Answer (score 3):

That’s the beauty of `sed`, it applies its paradigms to itself...  After the command (such as `s` or `tr` or nothing), the next character is considered the separator.

You should choose wisely to avoid interference with the shell and the command itself, and keep the thing readable, but it’s perfectly valid to write something as horrid as:

```
echo 'arrival' | sed srarbrg
```

...and get `brrivbl` as a result, which is what you expect. You can have fun making it really cryptic, such as in:

```
echo 'arrival' | sed s\fa\fb\fg   # \f is form feed, chr(12)
```

The common use is to use the slash as delimiter, but when your expression contains the delimiter, it makes it easier to grab what the intent is. Your delimiter can be anything in the ASCII8 range (multibyte delimiters such as `£` provoke an error).

Just remember the goal is to make things easier, not more cryptic.

Comment: Running with the cryptic idea, this is a valid sed command, though it doesn't do anything useful: `sed "snack is an apple or something" <<< "I sed your snack is an apple or something"`

Comment: Nice! Yes, you can use `sed` commands as brain teasers too, how geeky is that?